# ChromeDriver "cannot create default profile directory"

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium with python, and I'm trying to use some arguments for starting the chromedriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

def buildDriver():
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--profile-directory="Default"')
    options.add_argument('--user-data-dir="C:/Temp/ChromeProfile"')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver = buildDriver()
```

I have not been able to find a solution to the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot create default profile directory

Googling this error doesn't result in anything meaningful, at least not for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turns out you cannot use quotes when adding an argument.

```
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:/Temp/ChromeProfile')
```

Notice that it's `--profile-directory=Default` instead of `--profile-directory="Default"`

This is what fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:/Temp/ChromeProfile')

i had the same issue and for me, a changed the -- for ==

Comment: THANK YOU! After 2 hours of searching the web your tip finally worked for me: Change "--" to "=="

Comment: I have no idea why this works. And it doesn't look likely, but it seems to have worked for me! Thanks.